# Correct usage of File.Exists within dataGridView data row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a windows form that from a button click fills the dataGridView with the contents of a table inside a MS Access DB. Each row is information about a different movie file, Such as title, year, quality etc. Now column number 7 is a file location field. It stores a file path to the specific movie. I am trying to using `File.Exists` to evaluate whether the file actually exists in its location and if not it highlights the row red. Now it does not seem to highlight the correct rows. I have been tried a few different solutions finding really by looking up examples elsewhere and then by trial and error getting to the point I am at. However I suspect the issue is in my for/foreach loops and I am struggling to solve it. Was hoping someone could help me try and solve where I am going wrong

```
private void buttonShowAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from movies", connParam);
    OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    dAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
            dataTable.Rows[i][0], // ID
            dataTable.Rows[i][1], // Title
            dataTable.Rows[i][2], // Year
            dataTable.Rows[i][3], // Genre 1
            dataTable.Rows[i][4], // Genre 2
            dataTable.Rows[i][5], // Genre 3
            dataTable.Rows[i][6], // Quality
            dataTable.Rows[i][7]  // Location
            );
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            int j = 0; j++;
            string MovieLocation = row["movie_location"].ToString();

            if (!File.Exists(MovieLocation))
            {

                this.dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[j].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what value do you get when you debug this line `string MovieLocation = row["movie_location"].ToString();`

Comment: The Watch shows MovieLocation with value "D:\\1.txt"

Comment: does the file exist.. on your side..? if if does then what do you expect..? also you need to `break;` vs `return;` to jump out of that loop

Comment: The file does exist on my end, I figured out the break also. When it populates the datagridview it highlights the second item in the list regardless of whether the file exists or not and then ignores all the other records

Comment: I have noticed actually that the string value it is holding when i inspect it in the debug auto window actually is using a double backslash in the directory structure of the filepath i assume its adding an additional slash as an escape character but its not store in the db with an additional slash so i am unsure how to rectify that

Comment: incorrect assumption if you want to see the file path as a literal then you can assign the variable prefixed with `@` symbol double back slashes is how file paths are resolved in C# single back slashes are interpreted as escape chars. something is definitely wrong with your logic is my guess

Comment: I figured it out this morning, part of the issue was the watch window was re-escaping my string. using the text visualizer proves this case. But yes there was a logic flaw later. Thanks for the reply!